# Correct syntax to pass variable inside the setBadgeText

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a small extension, that will also display the amount of tabs open with macthing URL, as a badge, and I'm a complete beginner when it comes to coding...

I'm using a query to get the amount of tabs, which is stored as foundtabs.length. I tried to pass it through a variable, but I'm pretty sure I'm getting the syntax wrong...

```
function UpdateCount(){
    chrome.tabs.query({url: 'http://localhost:4848/sense/app/*'}, 
foundTabs => {
        var Test3 = foundTabs.length
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: Test3});
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: '#4688F1'});
    });
};
```

I also tried to put directly foundtabs.length instead of Test3, but didn't worked either

I expect the badge to match the length of foundTabs, correctly diplaying the amount of tabs opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is correct but you need to convert your **number** to **string** manually:

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: String(Test3)});
```

The reason for that is the API wants each property's type to match the [documented signature](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setBadgeText):

- **string**  text
- **integer** (optional) tabId